# Oracle SQL query to retrieve common users across roles

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table that has two columns of interest with data like following:

```
ROLES                   USERS
--------------------    ------------------------------
WEBAPP1 User            adams16
WEBAPP1 User            adams23
WEBAPP1 User            adams56
WEBAPP1 User            ford1
WEBAPP1 User            clerk23
WEBAPP1 User            miller2
WEBAPP1 User            ward3
WEBAPP1 User            jones21
WEBAPP1 User            martin12
WEBAPP1 User            li21
WEBAPP2 User            ford1
WEBAPP2 User            aboud1
WEBAPP2 User            clerk23
WEBAPP2 User            abraham2
WEBAPP2 User            aceves1
WEBAPP2 User            adams16
WEBAPP2 User            adams23
WEBAPP2 User            adams56
WEBAPP2 User            geronimo2
WEBAPP3 User            algrove3
WEBAPP3 User            allen2
WEBAPP3 User            jones21
WEBAPP3 User            king15
WEBAPP3 User            king20
WEBAPP3 User            king41
WEBAPP3 User            turner1
WEBAPP3 User            villiers3
WEBAPP4 User            alonso4
WEBAPP4 User            alvarez3
WEBAPP4 User            alviso1
```

I can find out which users are in a role:

```
ROLES                   USERS
--------------------    ------------------------------
WEBAPP1 User            adams16, adams23, adams56, ford1, clerk23, miller2, ward3, jones21, martin12, li21
WEBAPP2 User            abraham2, aboud1, aceves1, adams16, adams23, adams56, clerk23, ford1, geronimo2
WEBAPP3 User            algrove3, allen2, jones21, king15, king20, king41, turner1, villiers3
WEBAPP4 User            alonso4, alvarez3, alviso1
```

What roles users have:

```
USERS                   ROLES
--------------------    ------------------------------
aboud1                  WEBAPP2
abraham2                WEBAPP2
aceves1                 WEBAPP2
adams16                 WEBAPP1, WEBAPP2
adams23                 WEBAPP1, WEBAPP2
adams56                 WEBAPP1, WEBAPP2
...
```

What I would like to find is the list of users that have the most common roles. For e.g.,

```
COMMON USERS                        COMMON ROLES
--------------------                ------------------------------
adams16, adams23, adams56, ford1    WEBAPP1, WEBAPP2
aboud1                              WEBAPP2
...
```

This list would start with the largest set of users that have the same roles in common and a list of those roles followed by the next largest set of users and the role list and so on.

How do I achieve this? I'm trying to find groups of roles that have users in common. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do this by using `listagg()` twice (or in earlier versions of Oracle, `wm_concat()`.  Something like this:

```
select roles, listagg(user, ', ') within group (order by user) as users
from (select user, listagg(role, ', ') within group (order by role) as roles
      from userroles
      group by user
     ) ur
group by roles;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, this returns a ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long error. I had come across this when performing the user-roles, role-users queries and I had setup a clobagg function as described in https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402#29842804516386 - this doesn't help here with the GROUP BY roles. There is also a stragg function - that gives ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small error.

Comment: @RRAX69 . . . I would suggest that you explore your data and figure out which users have so many roles that they are causing the overflow (or perhaps which roles have so many users).  Then you can filter the data to get what you want without an error.  But, this suggests that the very thing you are looking for isn't reasonable.  Putting lists of things into strings with hundreds or thousands of characters doesn't make for understandable results.